# How can GLSurfaceView use my EGLDisplay, EGLContext and eglSurface?

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview, egl

I want to render alternatively to an EGLSurface created with eglCreateWindowSurface and one with eglCreatePbufferSurface, reusing the EGLDisplay and EGLContext. I am using a GLSurfaceView for the case when I want the result to be visible to the user, but I don't know how to initialize it to use my EGLDisplay, EGLContext and EGLSurface. I want to use GLSurfaceView.EGLWindowSurfaceFactory, but I see its override method createWindowSurface already has as input params those variables, so I suppose thy are already created by GLSurfaceView. How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of `GLSurfaceView` is to manage things like that for you, so it's hard to make it do what you want.

One thing you can do is to wait until the `GLSurfaceView` is created and then create a second EGL context in a share group.  This is a bit awkward but can be made to work.  In many ways it's simpler to just switch to `SurfaceView` or `TextureView` and manage EGL and threading yourself.

You can see various implementations in [Grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika).  "Show + capture camera" uses `GLSurfaceView` with a shared `EGLContext`, "Record GL app with FBO" uses `SurfaceView`, "Play movie (TextureView)" uses a `TextureView`, etc.